# Vulcan Nerve/Shoulder Pinch part of a larger system of martial arts that apparently use "psychic" abilities?

Tags: star-trek, vulcan, psychic, martial-arts, psychology

The nerve pinch has been seen multiple times. Although Spock spoke once of trying to teach Kirk the technique, I wonder if there is some aspect that means an untrained human can't do it or even a human simply can not do it even with training.

Is the Vulcan Nerve Pinch related to, for example, the "Mind Meld" and perhaps is part of a broader system of Vulcan self-defense/martial arts that relies on what we would call "psychic" abilities?

EDIT: Even if the Pinch does not require psychic powers, is it part of a broader system of martial arts that I guess would be called "pressure points"?

Comment: [Some cases of non-Vulcans using it](https://youtu.be/E8CHSpIWyfU?t=13), which suggest that it doesn't require psychic abilities.

Comment: A Kirk from an alternate timeline did one in an episode that only came out a few days ago.

Answer (score 7):

It does not appear like the nerve pinch relies on psychic abilities to work:

- We see Picard execute one in TNG: Starship Mine, on one of the terrorists. While he may have learned the technique during his mind meld with Sarek, that cannot magically given Picard psychic powers that his human physiology would otherwise be incapable of.
- In TNG: Unification, Part II, even Data performs a Vulcan nerve pinch.

Comment: Picard merely did a carotid-artery block though obviously it would have been vastly cooler if it were a Vulcan neck pinch.  The topic has a precedent on this site.